# How to click the button according to its text JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML code and script to click on button according to it's text, but it doesn't work.
Simple code to show what I did:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick=alert("clicked")>Try it</button>

<script>
document.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Try it')]")).click();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I also used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52405456/).

Comment: You're mixing Java code that uses the selenium webdriver to control a browser instance, with in-browser JavaScript code. The two languages might look similar at first but are very different and incompatible.

Comment: @ChrisG Java != JavaScript

Comment: @Marc Come again...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution you can try:

```
var searchText = "Check it";
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button=>{
    if(button.innerText == searchText) button.click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find element by xpath, use [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) instead

```js
document.evaluate(
  "//button[text()='Try it']",
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
  null
).singleNodeValue.click()
```

```html
<button onclick=alert("clicked")>Try it</button>
```